# Dynamic assigning of event listener for multiple classes is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, addeventlistener

Im struggling to find problem.

**Idea behind code**: 
dynamically assign event listener "oninput" to specific inputs on page determined by classes stored in "classes" array.

**Problem**:
function PassValue does not handle any element event where class is different from the last index in "classes" array(only the last class in array is handled).

When I change order of "class" array elements it results in different class being handled - again class on last index in array.

[Image of how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK9u8.png) (or check Snippet)

When I hover over console element in first part "Datum" should be highlighed just as "Blast KD" is on second part. Its simplified representation of when I Type something in them, same text should appear in input under them, but that works only for one of them.

**Question:**
Does anyone know why is it happening and how to fix it(so all inputs are handled)?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.constant-select-form-numeric').attr('list', 'consoptions-numeric');
  $('.constant-select-form-numeric-NT').attr('list', 'consoptions-numeric-NT');
  $('.constant-select-form-date').attr('list', 'consoptions-date');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var classes = ['.constant-select-form-date', '.constant-select-form-numeric', '.constant-select-form-numeric-NT'];
  var form = $(document).find('form');
  for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    var c = classes[j];
    //console.log(c);
    var e = $(document).find(c);
    if (e.length > 0) {

      // ... switch(c) differentiating classes from each other(assingning atributes)
      switch (c) {
        case '.constant-select-form-date':
          form[0].innerHTML += "<datalist id='consoptions-date'>\n\
<option data-value='-1'>Unknown</option>\n\
</datalist>";
          break;
        case '.constant-select-form-numeric-NT':
          form[0].innerHTML += "<datalist id='consoptions-numeric-NT'>\n\
<option data-value='-2'>NT</option>\n\
</datalist>";
          break;
        default:
          form[0].innerHTML += "<datalist id='consoptions-numeric'>\n\
<option data-value='-3'>NA</option>\n\
</datalist>";
          break;
      }

      // assign EventListener to each element of c
      for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        var element = $("input[for=" + e[i].attributes.for.value + "]")[0];
        var hidden = $("input[name=" + e[i].attributes.for.value + "]")[0];
        element.value = hidden.value;
        element.addEventListener("input", function(elem) {
          PassValue(elem.target);
        });
        PassValue(element);
        //print element DOM
        console.log(element);
      }
    }
  }
});

function PassValue(element) {
  console.log(element);
  var x = element.value;
  console.log(x);
  // rest of function...
  var hiddenInput = $(document).find("input[name=" + element.attributes.for.value + "]")[0];
  hiddenInput.value = x;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="datum">Datum: </label>
      <input for=datum class="form-control constant-select-form-date">
      <input type="text" name="datum" id="frm-newMessageForm-datum">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="datum1">Datum1: </label>
      <input for=datum1 class="form-control constant-select-form-date">
      <input type="text" name="datum1" id="frm-newMessageForm-datum1">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="blast_kd">Text: </label>
      <input for=blast_kd class="form-control constant-select-form-numeric">
      <input type="text" name="blast_kd" id="frm-newMessageForm-blast_kd">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="blast_kd1">Text1: </label>
      <input for=blast_kd1 class="form-control constant-select-form-numeric">
      <input type="text" name="blast_kd1" id="frm-newMessageForm-blast_kd1">
    </fieldset>    
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**Nevermind, I solved it with completely different approach on different layer.**(adding db constant fields is supposed to be in different layer, not in js)

Comment: You'd find this **so** much easier if you just used jquery *or* vanilla javascript throughout.  Looping through e?  `e.each(function() { ..this.attr("for")... ` etc

Comment: Remark: some inputs for attribute value are not double quoted.